# Regroup specific items in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, logic

This weekend I have been looking for a way to regroup items in an array without any success. I have been looking at the **reduce()** method, to regroup consecutive numbers in an array, although it would require to map the index of each item, which quickly becomes an unreadable mess.

I could **not** find the correct **terms** to find similar questions on Stack Overflow. Apologies if this is a duplicated question.

```
// Initial array:

foo = ["a", "b", "C", "D", "e", "f", "G", "H", "I", "j", "k", "l", "M", "n" ]

// Desired array:

bar = ["a", "b", ["C", "D"], "e", "f", ["G", "H", "I"], "j", "k", "l", ["M"], "n" ]
```

This simple illustration is self-explanatory and represents the problem I am trying to resolve.

Comment: What is the logic behind the internal arrays of the desired one? Could you please explain a bit more? Thanks!

Comment: It is only theoretical: for example, parsing each lines of a textarea would return an item per line in an array. What if I'd want to regroup list items under an unordered list tag? This is where this could be useful to do such operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function regroupArray(array) {
  let temp = array.map(el => (el >= "A" && el <= "Z" ? [el] : el));
  temp.forEach((el, i, arr) => {
    if (Array.isArray(el)) {
      while (Array.isArray(arr[i + 1])) {
        arr[i] = arr[i].concat(arr[i + 1]);
        arr.splice(i + 1, 1);
      }
    }
  });
  return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to regroup items in an array is to simply replace the items with an array of them. You can do this with the array.splice method like this:
`foo.splice(1, 2, [foo[2], foo[3]]);`
This will replace index 2 - 3 in the array with the exact same values, but inside an array.

Comment: ```let foo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
foo.splice(2, 3, [foo[2], foo[3]]);
console.log(foo);``` Hi, this doesn't work.

Comment: The two first arguments have to be decremented by one, because now youre replacing the third and the fourth elements.

Answer (score 0):

Go thru loop, Check if the char is capital letter.

If capital letter, then push temp array otherwise push result array.

When sequence is moving from capital to lower, push the temp array to result array.

```js
const foo = ["a", "b", "C", "D", "e", "f", "G", "H", "I", "j", "k", "l", "M", "n" ];

const isCapital = char_code => {
  const [start, end] = "AZ".split("").map(x => x.charCodeAt(0));
  return char_code >= start && char_code <= end;
};

const temp_arr = [];
const res = [];

for (let i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {
  const currCharCode = foo[i].charCodeAt(0);
  const currIsCapital = isCapital(currCharCode);

  if (temp_arr.length > 0) {
    // prev is capital
    const prevCharCode = temp_arr[temp_arr.length - 1].charCodeAt(0);
    if (currIsCapital && prevCharCode + 1 === currCharCode) {
      temp_arr.push(foo[i]);
    } else {
      res.push([...temp_arr]);
      temp_arr.length = 0;
      res.push(foo[i]);
    }
  } else {
    if (currIsCapital) {
      temp_arr.push(foo[i]);
    } else {
      res.push(foo[i]);
    }
  }
}

console.log(res);
```